# How to Find the Distinct Values in a DataBag?

Tags: apache-pig

Say I have some data like

```
1,A
1,A
1,B
2,C
2,D
3,E
3,E
```

I want to be able to group the first column and then return the distinct values in that group:

```
1,A,B
2,C,D
3,E
```

or

```
1,{A,B}
2,{C,D}
3,{E}
```

Is there a way to do this aside from a UDF?

If I do

```
DATA = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a:int, b:chararray);

GROUPED = GROUP DATA BY a;

UNIQUES = FOREACH GROUPED {
    distinct_bs = DISTINCT GROUPED.b;
    GENERATE
        group AS a
        ,FLATTEN(distinct_bs)
    ;
}
```

(regardless of FLATTEN or not, or if I include the `group as a`, I receive a

```
ERROR 1200: org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.ScalarExpression
cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.ProjectExpression
```

Comment: I spent hours on this last night, getting the same result as @Fred.  I don't believe it can be gotten into key,{$n} format without a UDF, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

GROUPED does not contain b, but DATA does:

```
DESCRIBE GROUPED
GROUPED: {group: int,DATA: {(a: int,b: chararray)}}
```

Try the following:

```
UNIQUES = FOREACH GROUPED {
    distinct_bs = DISTINCT DATA.b;
    GENERATE
        group AS a,
        distinct_bs;
}
```

Results in:

```
(1,{(A),(B)})
(2,{(C),(D)})
(3,{(E)})
```